# Error using activateConstraints on a collection of Container View constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes, uicontainerview

In my iOS 8 app using size classes, to get the iPad to have a different layout in portrait and landscape I have an `IBOutletCollection` for each orientation that I activate and deactivate.  This has worked great up until the introduction of a Container View.

I'm adding a new VC that is a separate tab item in the iPhone version, but I embed it into the iPad layout using a Container View.  I'll focus on just one size class, RegularRegular.  The container view has 4 constraints: Trailing, Leading, Top, and Bottom.  When I run the app, it looks fine (in that single orientation).

Now, when I add these 4 constraints to my `IBOutletCollection`, the `activateConstraints` message fails with the following error message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with items ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {460, 78}> and > because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

The constraints don't reference items in different view hierarchies.  Top, Bottom, and Leading are all in relation to another view that is also in the VC's view.  The Trailing is in relation to a stepper that is also in the VC's view.  So they're all at the same hierarchal level to my knowledge.

When in debug, I can see that the constraint starts off with its `active` property as `nil`.  This appears to be normal (the non-container constraints started off the same prior to them being set to `YES`).  I checked this with a for loop setting the `active` property.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the constraints on the Container View?  Are constraints on a Container View somehow special because they are on a Container View?  I've tried finding the answer myself, but I can't seem to find anything in regard to this issue I'm having.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*4/10 Edit to provide pictures & code.  Note at this time I've broken out the container constraints into a separate array so I can deal with them on their own.*

In the image below, the container's Leading, Top, and Bottom constraints are in relation to the view to the right of the container.  The Trailing constraint is in relation to the stepper above it.
[image: VC Layout]

Related code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *regularAnyConstraints;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *regularAnyContainerConstraints;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *anyRegularConstraints;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *anyRegularContainerConstraints;
```

These are the constraints in the `_anyRegularContainerConstraints` array:
[image: _anyRegularContainerConstraints]

```
[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:_regularAnyConstraints];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:_anyRegularConstraints];

[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:_anyRegularContainerConstraints];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:_anyRegularContainerConstraints];
```

Answer (score 1):

> When in debug, I can see that the constraint starts off with its active property as nil

That remark makes me wonder whether you might be misinterpreting what `activateConstraints` and `deactivateConstraints` do. Despite their names, and despite the misleading entry in the documentation, they actually add and remove constraints. Thus, instead of confusing yourself with these commands, I would suggest you might do better to call `addConstraints` and `removeConstraints` directly. The advantage of doing this is:

- These latter are UIView methods, so you will be in conscious control of what view the constraints are added to.
- When removing, you will be clear on your responsibility to retain the removed constraints if you want to use them again later.

I realize that this doesn't answer your question directly, but you didn't provide enough info for that (you didn't show your code that calls `activateConstraints` and `deactivateConstraints`, you didn't show any diagram of the view controller and view hierarchies, etc.) so it is not entirely clear where you are going wrong. Instead, I'm trying to get you to reorient your *thinking* as you try to work out the details of the problem.

Comment: I tried that, but seem to still be getting a hierarchy error, which makes me think there's definitely something wrong with my hierarchy, but I don't know what.
`[self.containerView removeConstraints:_regularAnyContainerConstraints];
[self.containerView addConstraints:_anyRegularContainerConstraints];`
Error message:
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1ae970 UIView:0x7a1ae9a0.bottom == UIView:0x7a0546a0.bottom>
 When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself).

Comment: Well, container views _are_ special in a fairly obvious way. I guess my next suggestion would be: can you reduce this issue to a very simple project? You could then post it at github and I would then download it and look at the details.

Comment: I should have tried to simplify it from the start.  I'm having no issues activating and deactivating constraints against a Container View from my test project.  I need to research the differences between it and my app project further.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not that surprised. :) I find that making a simplified version of a problem is often the best way to start debugging the problem. If the bug is still there, it's simpler, and if the bug is not there, you know that the issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the container view was not 'installed' at the time the constraints were being applied.  I am de/activating out of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` so at that time the size class must not yet be determined.

To resolve this I now have the Container View installed for AnyAny.  Then I deselected all of the size classes that I don't want it present for.

I eventually discovered this was the issue because my Container View's `UIView` was not in `self.view.subviews`.